# Convert SQL into linq to sql - group by two columns and request count of a third column

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server, linq

This is how the query looks in SQL:

```
select count(SnpId_this), DrugId, VariantId from tbl_custom_SNPs_All
join tbl_custom_SNP_Variants on VariantId = SnpsVariantId_this
join tbl_custom_SNP_Drugs_Apelon_NUIs on DrugId = SnpsDrugId_this
group by DrugId, VariantId
```

Here is my attempt using linq-to-sql:

```
var drugVariantGroups = 
    (from a in adminDB.tbl_custom_SNPs_Alls
     join v in adminDB.tbl_custom_SNP_Variants 
         on a.VariantId equals v.SnpsVariantId_this
     join d in adminDB.tbl_custom_SNP_Drugs_Apelon_NUIs 
         on a.DrugId equals d.SnpsDrugId_this
     group a by new { a.VariantId, a.DrugId } into dv
     select new
     {
         dv.Key.VariantId,
         dv.Key.DrugId,
         Entries = dv.Sum()
     }).ToList();
```

looks like dv does not have a definition for sum. How do I access SnpId_this to count it?

Comment: Can you post an example of what the SQL returns and what the linq-to-sql returns?

Answer (score 1):

Just use `Count`.  You may need to filter any entries where `SnpId_this` is null if that is a possibility and to precisely match the T-SQL.

```
Entries = dv.Where(t => t.SnpId_this != null).Count()
```

Answer (score 0):

You want Count not Sum:

```
var drugVariantGroups = 
    (from a in adminDB.tbl_custom_SNPs_Alls
     join v in adminDB.tbl_custom_SNP_Variants 
         on a.VariantId equals v.SnpsVariantId_this
     join d in adminDB.tbl_custom_SNP_Drugs_Apelon_NUIs 
         on a.DrugId equals d.SnpsDrugId_this
     group a by new { a.VariantId, a.DrugId } into dv
     select new
     {
         dv.Key.VariantId,
         dv.Key.DrugId,
         Entries = dv.Count()
     }).ToList();
```

If you want sum you should provide the field to use in Sum function like:

`dv.Sum(c=>c.Amount)`